# How to construct $\Delta ABC$, given the angle at $C$ , $\gamma$ the median drawn fom $C$, $t_c$, and the angle at the point $B$, $\beta$?

Tags: triangles, geometric-construction

I've gotten stuck again, can't seem to figure out what I'm supposed to construct first.
[[image: IMAGE: A triangle, <span class=]$\Delta ABC$ with $\gamma$, $\beta$ and $t_c$ marked. Next to it text reads: $\gamma$ = $\angle ACB$, $\beta$ = $\angle ABC$ and $t_c$ = median of $c$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cU4r6.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

Construct a triangle with angles $\gamma$ and $\beta$; let $t'_c$ be the corresponding median.  Then perform a homothety with center $C$ and ratio $t_c/t'_c$.